# Can't think how to remove digits from list - Scheme

Tags: scheme

This is my function:

```
(define (remove-digit digit list)
  (cond ((null? list ...))
    (( = (car list) digit) (remove-digit digit (cdr list)))
      (else (cons (car list) (if (null? list) (cons(remove-digit digit (cdr list))))))is:
```

and it should do this:

(1 2 4 5 2 5 6) after (remove-digit 2 list) should be (1 4 5 5 6)

but I can't think what to do when the list becomes null.

Can you please give me a little help or some kind of idea? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return an empty list (or the `list` itself). It is the base case for your function.

```
(define (remove-digit digit list)
  (cond ((null? list) list)
        ((= digit (car list)) (remove-digit digit (cdr list)))
        (else (cons (car list) (remove-digit digit (cdr list))))))
```

To deduce base case easily think about "minimal" case of `remove-digit` with an empty list as a parameter.

```
(remove-digit digit '())
```

It should return `'()` obviously for any `digit` value one supplies.